# Time complexity of function that depends on max list value...?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I currently have designed a function that partitions a list of integers into a 2 sublists (of size n/2) such that the difference in sums between the two lists is maximized.

The pseudocode looks like this:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < list_size ; i++ )
    if (list[i] > max) list_max = list[i]

int array[list_max];

for ( i =0; i < list_size ; i++ )
    array[list[i]]++

for ( i = 0; i < list_max ; i++ )
    //compute sums of two lists from array
```

I figure the first two for loops are O(n), however I have no idea how to think about the time complexity of the third loop...

Comment: Perhaps you want to write the time complexity in terms of the size of the input data rather than the length of the list? Otherwise, your function is not bounded by any function of only n.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few things to consider here and an easy way to approach this problem is to analyze each loop.

1. > O(n)

   The first loop clearly runs n times where n denotes the `list_size`
2. > O(n)

   This second loop runs the same as the first
3. > O(m)

   This loop runs m times where m denotes the `list_max`

So we add this all together and get:

> O(n + n + m) => O(2n + m) => O(n + m)

Comment: Where would the O(n+m) bounding lie in relation to O(n), O(n^2), etc...or is that impossible to determine?

Comment: @dgbarrett I believe it would be bound under O(n) because recall for big o we care about any upper bound function given an arbitrary constant, therefore no matter the value of n and m, we can always find a constant c that would make O(n) an upper bound of O(n + m). I could be wrong though, this is just my thought process for that and how I'd personally answer it

Comment: @dgbarrett Also, O(n + m) is still linear, which is more evidence backing my idea that O(n) is an upper bound

Comment: Imagine if m was n^2 or m was n!. So you can not make any assumption on m, hence it is O(n + m).

Comment: @SelçukCihan so would you say it's bounded under O(n+m)?

Comment: Exactly, that is the tightest bound.

Comment: @SelçukCihan oh okay, thank you for clearing that up!!

Comment: However, if we take the limit as n approaches inf. of (n+m)/(n) = 1.  So thus it is O(n), no?

Comment: Since if `m` was a value `>=n` then it could not be bounded under O(n), I would think *no*, but I'd like to see @SelçukCihan 's thoughts on this

Comment: @dgbarrett try to take the limit for the case when m equals n^2. Unless we are given an equation of m in terms of n or m is just a constant, we can't speculate on m, hence we leave it as it is that is O(n+m).

Answer (score 0):

When you have two for-loop inside your function, you can say its complexity is O(n + k) (considering n = list_size and k = list_max).